# How to fix "Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: Unable to load application."

Tags: php, zend-framework3

I create my project affter install Zend-framework 3, and I add module Album acording to Zend tutorial, I finished all task but I can't start my website on localhost

```php
Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: Unable to load application.
- Type `composer install` if you are developing locally.
- Type `vagrant ssh -c 'composer install'` if you are using Vagrant.
- Type `docker-compose run zf composer install` if you are using Docker. in C:\xampp\htdocs\abc\public\index.php:25 
Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\abc\public\index.php on line 25
```

Please help me, I don't know how to fix it. :(

Comment: Did you run "composer install", as suggested by the error message ?

Comment: `Please help me, I don't know how to fix it. :(` - I mean... it tells you what to do?

Comment: `I create my project affter install Zend-framework 3` - what did you do and how did you do it? This error occurs when you've made a mistake in that part. Going to need more info ...